# После импорта дампа дб белый экран смерти

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь сделать импорт базы данных для Word press сайта. Импорт происходит, но сайт показывает белый экран смерти. В админку пускает, никакие темы и плагин не ставил. Как можно дебажить, или на что обратить внимание в импорте, что может давать конфликт.

Comment: Читать логи ошибок на сервере

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_7791/debag-v-wordpress-wp_debug.html

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/767561/220220

Answer (score 0):

1. Логи в админке хостинга.
2. Логи в фтп.
3. Логи в браузере - инструменты разработчика (много полезной инфы выводится).